# Jquery calling function methods - function_name() vs funcion_name.call(this)

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I would like to know what is the difference between these two methods for calling a function in jquery plugins

```
function foo() {
    //Do something
}

function init() {

    foo.call(this);

    // or

    foo();
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a jQuery thing, it's a JavaScript thing. It determines what `this` will be during the call.

With `foo()`, during the call to `foo`, `this` will be either the global object (loose mode) or `undefined` (strict mode).

With `foo.call(x)`, during the call to `foo`, `this` will be `x`. So `foo.call(this)` ensures that `this` during the call to `foo` is the same as `this` where you're calling it.

More *(on my blog)*:

- [*Mythical methods*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)
- [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)

Comment: Is this the same thing then? func() and func.call() ? thanks

Comment: @Gus: The first argument to `call` [is not optional](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.4). In loose mode, `foo()` is the same as `foo.call(theGlobalObject)` (where `theGlobalObject` is a reference to the global object; on browsers you can get this from `window`). In strict mode, `foo()` is the same as `foo.call(undefined)`.